# Microsoft SQL Server PDO Connection Error - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect my website to an SQL database that I have on Microsoft SQL Server Management. I'm using XAMPP. It allows me to sign with the servername and username credentials. When I use those same credentials via my PDO connection PHP code, it throws up this error. Anyone know what might be causing this?

I have tried looking at Server properties and my permissions are allowed. Here is my connection file.

```
<?php
$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "";
$dbname = "....";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, why does your connection string look like a MySQL connection?

Comment: Is this how it should be instead? 

try {
  $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: because now I get a different error that says 'could not find driver'

Comment: Please confirm your technology stack. You say you're using XAMPP, but that uses MariaDB (basically MySQL) for its database service as opposed to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: XAMP - Apache and MySQL modules. I understand this is a very novice question but how could I switch to using SQL SERVER connection?